# Sums of Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $U$ is the set of all elements of $\mathbb{F^{3}}$ whose first and second coordinates equal $0$, and $W$ is the set of all elements  of $\mathbb{F^{3}}$ whose first and third coordinates equal $0$.

$U = \{(x,0,0) \in \mathbb{F^{3}}: x \in \mathbb{F}\}$ and $W = \{(0,y,0) \in \mathbb{F^{3}}: x \in \mathbb{F}\}$.

Then

**1.7**: $U + W = \{(x,y,0):x,y \in \mathbb{F}\}$

This part makes sense to me. However, it is needed for the next part of the problem.

Now, suppose that $U$ is as above and $W$ is the set of all elements of $\mathbb{F^{3}}$ whose first and second coordinates are equivalent, with the third coordinate equal to $0$:

$W = \{(y,y,0) \in \mathbb{F^{3}}: y \in \mathbb{F}\}$.

Then $U + W$ is also given by **1.7**, as you should verify. <-- this very last sentence is the source of confusion.

Wouldn't $U + W$ be $(x,0,0) + (y,y,0) = (x + y, y, 0)$ rather than simply $(x,y,0)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're correct. If given an arbitrary vector $(x, y, 0)$, you can obtain it as the sum

$$(x, y, 0) = (x - y, 0, 0) + (y, y, 0) \in U + W$$

Note that the argument in the original question is slightly backwards: it concludes that every element in $U + W$ has the form $(x, x + y, 0)$ for some $x, y$; but what we wish to show is that every vector of the form $(a, b, 0)$ can be found in $U + W$. This is essentially equivalent to showing that there are always solutions to $x = a, x + y = b$.

Comment: Hmm, this is making more sense. So $U$ can be expressed as $(x-y,0,0)$ as opposed to $(x,0,0)$. Does this mean that we are subtracting two vectors together inside of $U$, and then adding them to $W$?

Comment: @StVincent Yes, that's one way to think about it. In particular, we need to find a vector of a specific form to add to a vector in $W$ - note that in the original question, just noting that elements of $U + W$ have the form $(x + y, y, 0)$ isn't sufficient to show that you can hit every vector of the form $(a, b, 0)$.

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful